# Is this replacement word correct?

Tags: exam-questions

I had an English exam and there was a question that says to correct the sentence:

> They will have a meeting about concordance and patience reassurance.

I corrected "patience" to "patients". Is it correct?

Answer (score 5):

Nearly, but not quite. When a noun is used as a modifier for another noun, it is nearly always in the singular; so if you want to make "reassurance of patients*" into a noun-noun phrase it is "patient reassurance", not "patients reassurance", even though several patients might be involved.

**Edit** So the answer is "patient reassurance". 
"Patients reassurance" is comprehensible, but not what a native English speaker would use. 
"Patience reassurance" is meaningless, representing a mishearing.

*There are some exceptions, but they are established phrases like "women actors" (the subject of another thread here). If you are using a phrase which is not an established phrase, use the modifying noun in the singular.

Comment: So (Patience reassurance) is correct as in meaning and grammatically ?

Comment: No. "Patience reassurance" is meaningless - that is a confusion of the quite different words "patient" and "patience". I did say "patient reassurance", but not prominently: I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Just a question: Could _patients'_ work in this context?

Comment: @J.R.: yes, I think it could.